# How to concatenating the elements of an array with different length?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a `list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]`. I want to take out one element "4", then split the remaining list with `np.array_split(list1,5)`, I will get `[array([1, 2]), array([5, 6]), array([7, 8]), array([ 9, 10]), array([11])]` as  result. When I try to convert it into an pandas Data Frame, the out put result would be as:

| index | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2.0 |
| 1 | 5 | 6.0 |
| 2 | 7 | 8.0 |
| 3 | 9 | 10.0 |
| 4 | 11 | NaN |

But I want to get the result as just one column data frame with single value in each cell without `NaN` value at the end.

Any suggestion with this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want the output to be the same as the input? I think the question needs clarifying.

Comment: Can you try rephrasing your question? Currently the desired output is identical to the input.

Comment: `np.concatenate(np.array_split(list1, 5)).tolist()` But as others pointed out, you need more clarification?

Comment: What do you want instead of the NaN?  There has to be something in the cell.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your question, I just want the get the result like: 
[array([1]),array([2]), array([3]), array([4]),array([5]),.... 
the list containing single arrays. NOT arrays with two elements.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Then why the split.  That's what makes the groups of 2s, with an odd one that needs filling.  Do you just want a (9,1) shape array?

Answer (score 0):

Put your array into a dict and create your dataframe from that:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,77,8,9,0]
x = np.array_split(list1, 5)

df = pd.DataFrame({'column': x})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    column
0   [1, 2]
1   [3, 4]
2  [5, 77]
3   [8, 9]
4      [0]
```

Comment: But just a question, is there any way to change the data frame, in which the columns be like:
      column
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    77
6    8
7    9
10   0